# Mathematica Workspace

Tags: core-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there equivalence within Mathematica to view currently used variables similar to Matlab?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15351/is-there-equivalence-within-mathematica-to-view-currently-used-variables-similar)

In Matlab, I can type:

```
>> whos
>> x=4

x =

     4

>> y=7

y =

     7

>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  x         1x1                 8  double              
  y         1x1                 8  double
```

And I get a list of all variables in my workspace. Is there something similar in Mathematica so I know what variables to Clear?

Comment: Have you tried `?Global\`*` Will that work for you?

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi How did you use that font in a comment?

Comment: @belisarius $\LaTeX$

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Well if you use two ticks  on each side then it works: ``Clear["Global`∗"]``

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi thanks!