# How to list all user-defined variables with current values?

Tags: variable

How to get a list of all user-defined variables and those current values in the current .nb?
Maybe it's a (too) simple question, sorry if so, but the answer would help me a lot in debugging some stubborn code...

Comment: Strongly related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15351/is-there-an-equivalent-of-matlabs-workspace-window-in-mathematica).

Comment: Try 'Names[$Context <> "*"]' and 'Symbol /@ %'