# How to construct an IF statement within `Manipulate` with various stopping statements

Tags: manipulate, conditional, code-review, code-request

Take the following data:

```
countryMM = {
{{{0, 0.47, 0.07, 0.07, 0.14},
  {0.38, 0, 0.16, 0.13, 0.23}, 
  {0.29, 0.30, 0, 0.24, 0.35},
  {0.58, 0.39, 0.14, 0, 0.51},
  {0.15, 0.22, 0.06, 0.07, 0}},
{{0, 0.95, 0.30, 0.44, 0.42},
 {0.19, 0, 0.33, 0.40, 0.35},
 {0.07, 0.15, 0, 0.37, 0.26}, 
 {0.09, 0.13, 0.09, 0, 0.25}, 
 {0.05, 0.15, 0.08, 0.15, 0}}},
{{{0, 0.43, 0.06, 0.07, 0.14},
  {0.41, 0, 0.13, 0.13, 0.24},
  {0.30, 0.30, 0, 0.24, 0.37},
  {0.46, 0.32, 0.13, 0, 0.40},
  {0.17, 0.23, 0.06, 0.08, 0}},
 {{0, 0.90, 0.26, 0.45, 0.41},
  {0.19, 0, 0.27, 0.40, 0.34},
  {0.06, 0.14, 0, 0.35, 0.25},
  {0.07, 0.10, 0.09, 0, 0.19},
  {0.05, 0.16, 0.08, 0.16, 0}}}
};
```

and

```
priceTransmission = {
{1, 1.9, 1.3, 2.7, 1.5},
{0.4, 1, 0.6, 1.3, 0.7},
{0.7, 1.4, 1, 1.9, 1.1},
{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 1, 0.5},
{0.6, 1.2, 0.8, 1.7, 1}
};  

marketPower[c1_, c2_, c3_, c4_, c5_, c6_]  
:= { 
     {1, (1+c3), 1, (1+c4), (1+c6)}, 
     {(1+c1), 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
     {1, (1+c2), 1, 1, (1+c6)},
     {(1+c4), (1+c5), (1+c4), 1, (1+c2)},
     {(1+c2), (1+c1), (1+c3), 1, (1+c5)}
   };

sector = 5;
v = {AGF, CO12, MA1, MA2, EGW};
v1 = {1 -> "AGF", 2 -> "CO12", 3 -> "MA1", 4 -> "MA2", 5 -> "EGW"};
v2 = {"AGF", "CO12", "MA1", "MA2", "EGW"};
vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW};
labelsV = {AGF -> 1, CO12 -> 2, MA1 -> 3, MA2 -> 4, EGW -> 5};

legends = {"[1] AGF: Agriclture/hunting/fishery", "[2] CO12: Crude oil/mining", "[3] MA1: Manufacturing/petroleum refining", "[4] MA2: Manufacturing\[Dash]other", "[5] EGW: Electricity/gas/water supply"};

sectorLegends = {"AGF: Agriclture/hunting/fishery", "CO12: Crude oil/mining", "MA1: Manufacturing/petroleum refining", "MA2: Manufacturing\[Dash]other", "EGW: Electricity/gas/water supply"};

sectorFullNames = { "Agriclture/hunting/fishery", "Crude oil/mining",   "Manufacturing/petroleum refining", "Manufacturing\[Dash]other", "Electricity/gas/water supply"};

indCountry = { "ioMatrix[1]", "ioMatrix[2]"};
listCountry = { {CNT1, Country1}, {CNT2, Country2}};
countries = { "Country 1", "Country 2"};

Table[mpaPriceTrans[i][c1_, c2_, c3_,c4_, c5_, c6_] := marketPower[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6]*priceTransmission, {i,2}];
```

The above data are used in the following `Code`:

```
UnweightedTransmission[matrixA_?MatrixQ, matrixB_?MatrixQ, t1_Real,t2_Real] :=  Module[{indices = Union @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@FindPath[AdjacencyGraph[   Map[Boole[t1 <= # <= t2] &, matrixA, {-1}]], #[[1]], #2[[1]], \[Infinity], All])},    HighlightGraph[Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ indices, EdgeWeight -> Extract[matrixB, indices], EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ##3], {#, #2}]] &;

MultiplierWeightedTransmission[matrixA_?MatrixQ, matrixB_?MatrixQ,   t1_Real, t2_Real]:=Module[{indices = 
  Union @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
     FindPath[AdjacencyGraph[
       Map[Boole[t1 <= # <= t2] &, MatrixA, {-1}]], #[[1]], #2[[1]], \[Infinity], All])}, HighlightGraph[     Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ indices, EdgeWeight -> Extract[matrixA*matrixB, indices], EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ##3], {#, #2}]] &;

edgeW = Module[{g = #, e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;
subGraphF = Module[{el = edgeW[##][[All, 1]]}, Graph[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@el],      VertexCapacity -> {v_ :> PropertyValue[{#, v}, VertexCapacity]}, EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{#, e}, EdgeWeight]}]] &;

multiplierType = {"Backward Multiplier Matrix", "Forward Multiplier Matrix"};
transType = {UnweightedTransmission, MultiplierWeightedTransmission};
testType = {EdgeBetweennessCentrality, DegreeCentrality};

Manipulate[
Grid[{
{
Legended[
  DecimalForm[  
  gr = transType[[transmissionType]][
  countryMM[[Country, matrixType]], 
  mpaPriceTrans[Country][c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6], lowerBound,upperBound][Style[sourceTarget, Green], Style[sinkTarget, Red], VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v /. vLabels, Center]},       VertexSize -> 0.4, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLabel -> "Network of Reform and Impact Sectors", ImageSize -> 300], 2],
 Placed[SwatchLegend[{Green, Red}, {"Sector for policy reform", "Sector for policy impact"}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LabelStyle -> Black, LegendMarkers -> ChartElementData[SwatchLegend][[1]], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 20], Below]
 ], 
 DecimalForm[ 
 CommunityGraphPlot[gr, ConnectedComponents[gr], 
  CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, Method -> "Centrality", 
  ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotLabel -> "Communities in the Reform-Impact Network"], 2]
},
{
gr = Graph[gr, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[gr], 
  ImageSize -> 300];  (*fixes the vertex coordinates of "gr"*)
vRange = SortBy[VertexList[gr], N];
DecimalForm[{gr, VertexDelete[EdgeDelete[gr, IncidenceList[gr, deletedSectors]], {deletedSectors}]}, 2]},
   {
   pathvalue = {Table[
    Times @@ edgeW[gr, sourceTarget, sinkTarget][[i, 2]], {i, 
     Length[edgeW[gr, sourceTarget, sinkTarget]]}]} // Transpose;
  TableForm[
  Table[{{edgeW[gr, sourceTarget, sinkTarget][[i, 1]] /. 
     vLabels}, {pathvalue[[i]]}}, {i, 
   Length[edgeW[gr, sourceTarget, sinkTarget]]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Pathway", "Pathway Multiplier"}}],
Table[
  EdgeList[subGraphF[gr, sourceTarget, sinkTarget]][[i]], {i, 
   Ordering[
     testType[[signTestType]][
      subGraphF[gr, sourceTarget, sinkTarget]], -numSignLinks] // 
    Reverse}] /. vLabels,
 TableForm[Transpose@{sectorLegends}, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Sector names"}}]
 }
 }],
 Spacer[30],
 Delimiter,
Style["Country and Type of Multiplier Matrix", Bold, Medium],
{{Country, 1, "Choose a country"}, 
Thread[Range[Length[countries]] -> countries], 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{matrixType, 1, "Choose the type of multiplier matrix"}, 
Thread[Range[Length[multiplierType]] -> multiplierType], 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{transmissionType, 1, "Choose the type of price transmission"}, 
Thread[Range[Length[transType]] -> transType], 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
Delimiter,
Style["Multiplier Interval", Bold, Medium],
{{lowerBound, 0.01, "Choose a lower bound"}, 0.001, 1, 0.01, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{upperBound, 0.30, "Choose an upper bound"}, 0.001, 1, 0.01, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
Delimiter,
Style["Policy Reform-Impact Network and Communities", Bold, Medium], {{sourceTarget, 2, "Choose a sector for policy reform"}, 
Thread[Range[Length[sectorLegends]] -> sectorLegends], 
ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {{sinkTarget, 4, "Choose a sector for policy impact"}, Thread[Range[Length[sectorLegends]] -> sectorLegends], ControlType -> PopupMenu},
Delimiter,
Style["Significant Sectors", Bold, Medium],
{{signTestType, 1, "Choose a significance test type"}, 
Thread[Range[Length[testType]] -> testType], 
ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {{numSignLinks, 1, 
"Choose the number of most significant paths"}, Range[3], 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
Delimiter,
Style["Significant Sectors", Bold, Medium],
{{deletedSectors, vRange[[1]], 
"Choose a sector to test\n(by removing it from the red network)"}, Thread[vRange -> sectorLegends[[vRange]]], ControlType ->   PopupMenu},
Delimiter,
Style["Market Power Parameters for Upstream-Downstream Sectors", 
Bold, Medium],
{{c1, 0.10, "Case 1"}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c2, 0.20, "Case 2"}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c3, 0.40, "Case 3"}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c4, 0.08, "Case 4"}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c5, 0.06, "Case 5"}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c6, 0.04, "Case 6"}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", 
Style["Market power-adjusted price transmission network", Larger, 
 Bold, Black]}}
]
```

This is really the simplest example I could prepare for my question. For a given set of parameters, when I run this `Code` without using `Manipulate`, it just works nicely because there is no up and down in parameter setting when `Manipulate` is used. However, my goal is to run this `Manipulate`.

1. `vRange` is creating trouble. After constructing a graph, I find the vertex list of the graph, and from this list, I want to delete one vertex. (In fact, I want to delete more than one vertex at a time but I could not find the way to do it.) When I choose a vertex to delete using the `Control`, I receive an error message that `vRange` does not have the right form. What is wrong with the `vRange`? I use `If` statement to pick a feasible vertex from `vRange` but this `If` statement does not work either. `If` the vertex to be deleted is an element of `vRange` then I want to proceed with the deletion. If not, I just want to `Quit` with a message saying that `it is not feasible`.
2. I want to do the calculations at each step after confirming the calculations done at the earlier stages. For example, after picking a multiplier range in the second `Control`, I want to know whether the range is empty or not. If empty, then `Quite` with a message again `choose another range`. Basically, all the `Controls` should be confirmed one by one to establish a running `Manipulate`.

I will stop here because this has been a long question.

Comment: I have edited my question due to a missing part of the Code. Apologies. Now it should be working for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the line:

```
gr = Graph[gr, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[gr], ImageSize -> 300];
```

Just change gr to gr2 in two places (there may be others):

```
gr2 = Graph[gr, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[gr], ImageSize -> 300];
vRange = SortBy[VertexList[gr2], N];
```

Now your code runs inside the Manipulate without the vRange error. Of course, you still have other errors. The first one I see is that MatrixA is undefined.

Why does this happen? Manipulate is like a big loop construct... it runs the code over and over until nothing changes. If you have a structure like:

```
var = function[var]
```

then it will keep changing, perhaps forever.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I copied Your code and started to debug.

a) I entered on another input

```
vRange
```

b) I change the Range[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25li2.jpg) input and undid the change.

c) After each change I reran the code part input.

d) I got that result:

[image: GUI ran correct]

e) I changed the GUI selector dropdown field from top to bottom.

f) After changing the dropdown field

[image: warning list abbreviated after interruption, abortion]

[image: warning list abbreviated before interruption, abortion]

[image]

So to me the state of your question shows You are in need of cleaning up the notebook as a preparation for the next run. And than take care each input line is excuteted.

There is some help in debugging possible from mathematica.stackexchange.com. For example

- [mathematica debuggability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/mathematica-debuggability)
- [profiling from mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica/7769#7769)
- [how to abort on any message generated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-abort-on-any-message-generated)
- [ShowIt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15134/a-debug-utility-to-print-or-extract-intermediate-data-from-a-program)
- [is there an equivalent of matlabs workspace window in [image: mathematica workspace command in Your case]mathematica][10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15351/is-there-an-equivalent-of-matlabs-workspace-window-in-mathematica)

This very large. Bugtracking is harder than programming.

```
StateInspector[]
```

[image: working with upvalues and downvalues with]

You see by this investigation Your project is already really very huge. The analysis stopps my iMac with 8 GB form performing nicely at this stage.

Since this seeme to be a well design GUI and well though of background logic there is chance that my advice already suffices to reach a well operating state.

Comment: You have checked the Code thoroughly, and I can understand it up to a point but then I am lost because I do not know how to go on. I can get a full answer from the Code if I run it without using `Manipulate`. The Code does not have a problem at individual commands. But the `vRange` in the `Control` panel needs to update itself when I change the dimension of the directed graph. I am positive that if I can manage to make `vRange` a `Dynamic` variable then it will work because the Code works without `Manipulate`.